# EventLog functions returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, winapi

While trying to read and get number of events in an Event Log I am getting an error 87.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define PROVIDER_NAME "System"

void wmain(void)
{
    HANDLE hEventLog = NULL;
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    PDWORD numEvents = 0;

    hEventLog = OpenEventLog(NULL, PROVIDER_NAME);
    printf("Last error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    if (!GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEventLog, numEvents))
    {
        printf("Failed GetNumberOfEventLogRecords: %lu\n", GetLastError());

    }
```

Output:

```
Last error: 0
Failed GetNumberOfEventLogRecords: 87
```

I've tried with a few variants on the PROVIDER_NAME and I've based my example off this doc but once I do any kind of tweaking like my example I run into the ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/querying-for-event-source-messages

I am not sure what the incorrect parameter is in reference to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NumberOfRecords
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the number of records in the
>   specified event log.

You need to pass the address of a DWORD value, to get the number

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define PROVIDER_NAME "System"

int wmain(void)
{
    HANDLE hEventLog = NULL;
    DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    DWORD numEvents = 0;

    hEventLog = OpenEventLog(NULL, PROVIDER_NAME);
    printf("Last error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    if (!GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEventLog, &numEvents))
    {
        printf("Failed GetNumberOfEventLogRecords: %lu\n", GetLastError());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`GetNumberOfEventLogRecords()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getnumberofeventlogrecords):

> NumberOfRecords
>
> **A pointer to a variable** that receives the number of records in the specified event log.

Your `numEvents` variable is a `PDWORD` (`DWORD*`) pointer that has a value of 0.  So you are calling `GetNumberOfEventLogRecords()` with a NULL pointer in its `NumberOfRecords` parameter.  That is what the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error is complaining about - it has nowhere to write out the record count.

You need to pass in the address of an actual `DWORD` variable, not a NULL pointer.

Also, you should not be calling `GetLastError()` after `OpenEventLog()` unless it actually fails.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define PROVIDER_NAME "System"

void wmain(void)
{
    HANDLE hEventLog = NULL;
    DWORD numEvents = 0;
    ...

    hEventLog = OpenEventLog(NULL, PROVIDER_NAME);
    if (!hEventLog) {
        printf("Failed OpenEventLog: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else {
        if (!GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEventLog, &numEvents)) {
            printf("Failed GetNumberOfEventLogRecords: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
        CloseEventLog(hEventLog);
    }
}
```